# Python calling functions in terminal after modifying it

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I'm testing my functions written in a file using terminal. My system is Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7. I found that each time after I change the contents of the function then I execute again from terminal, it seems not apply the changes.

My actual aim is design functions and classes for Tensorflow calculation but for now, it should be simply an issue about Python.

I mean, firstly enter python environment in terminal and import the file let's say `import try_function as trf`, then call `trf.try1() #suppose it prints 'hello world'`. After I change the `try1()` to make it print `'hello'`, run it from terminal `trf.try1()`, it still prints `'hello world'`, even I tried to `import try_function as trf` again, it still not working. Can someone tell me how to keep the terminal executing up-to-date version of the codes? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload).

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module).

Comment: Thanks that helps, I'll need to simply `reload(trf)`